# Перенос слова Олеговна

Tags: перенос

Можно ли перенести отчество Олеговна вот так: Ол-еговна
или только Оле-говна

Answer (score 1):

Нет, конечно. В первом случае слово на слоги так не делится, а во втором... ну за что Вы с ней так?)))))) Лучше всего будет перенести: Олегов-на.